# How do you generate a EOA address with javascript?

Tags: javascript, eoa

With web3 you can use `web3.personal.newAccount` to generate a new EOA.
MyEtherWallet seems not to rely on its Geth node to generate such addresses. How would you generate EOA purely client side?